# why blocking operation created?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, blocking, mean-stack

Using `mean.io` stack, i have the following problem:

On testing with Apache bench, I found that simple query created blocking operation

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        async = require('async'),
        Post = mongoose.model('Post');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  Post.find({deleted:false}, function(err, posts) {
    if (err) {
      res.jsonp(err);
    } else {
      res.jsonp(posts);
    }
  });
};
```

ab -n 1 -c 1 http:// localhost:3000/home >
Time taken for tests:   0.006 seconds

ab -n 10 -c 10 http:// localhost:3000/home >
Time taken for tests:   0.032 seconds

ab -n 100 -c 100 http:// localhost:3000/home >
Time taken for tests:   0.224 seconds

Am i using the callbacks right, what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The concurrency of your MongoDB queries is limited to size of your connection pool, which is only 5 by default.

You can tweak that in your `mongoose.connect` call and you can set it to 100 to eliminate that as a bottleneck for your benchmarking:

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {server: {poolSize: 100}}, cback);
```

Comment: I set it to 100, and saw that in db.serverStatus().connections changed, but anyway Apache bench showing same result, so looks like impossible send few queries in one moment :(

tested - if put two queries in one method (second not in callback of first) it looks like queries going parallel in db